# digest-Fetch en app React

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Estoy teniendo un problema con el digest-fetch. A continuacion explico brevemente el error:

Usé el digest-fetch tal cual esta aca: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/digest-fetch
Pero mi problema es que cuando ejecuto el digest-fetch desde mi app react, el navegador me pide las credenciales, cosa que no entiendo porque le estoy enviado las credenciales en el constructor del digest-fetch.

Mi codigo:

```js
const DigestFetch = require('digest-fetch')
const digestOptions = {
 cnonceSize: 32,  // length of cnonce, default: 32
 logger: console, // logger for debug, default: none
 algorithm: 'MD5' // only 'MD5' is supported now
}
   
const client = new DigestFetch('admin', '1234', digestOptions) 
// do request same way as fetch or node-fetch
const url = 'http://localhost/rest/index.php/api/Example/users'
const init ={
 method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
 mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
 cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
 credentials: 'include', // include, *same-origin, omit
 headers: {                                
         'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',                                
 },
 redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
 referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
 body: null, // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
};

client.fetch(url,init)
 .then(resp=>resp.json())      
        .then(data=>console.log(data))
        .catch(e=>console.error(e))        
}
```

Foto del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya les agradezco mucho.